# VueJs 2 way data binding changes lost

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of products:
[image]

For each product they can select a time type (per hour, per day etc).
When they have done so and clicked book, it adds the product to cart;

this is done inside addToCart below on the line that is bolded.

```
 addToCart: function (resultId, cartId) {

                var that = this;

                 this.shoppingCart.forEach(function (cartItem, cartIndex) {

                     cartItem.added = false;

                     if (cartIndex == cartId)
                     {
                         cartItem.added = true;

                         that.results.forEach(function (resultItem, resultIndex) {

                             if (resultItem.id == resultId) {

                                 that.shoppingCart.$set(cartIndex,
                                             {
                                                 productTimeType: cartItem.productTimeType,
                                                 quantity  : cartItem.quantity                                                   
                                             });

                                     var numberOfBookings = (parseInt(resultItem.numberBookings, 10) + cartItem.quantity);

                                     that.results.$set(resultIndex, {
                                            numberBookings: numberOfBookings,
                                            name: resultItem.name,
                                            quantity: resultItem.quantity,
                                            id: resultItem.id,
                                            category_id: resultItem.category_id,
                                            description: resultItem.description,
                                            image: resultItem.image,
                                            created_at: resultItem.created_at,
                                            updated_at: resultItem.updated_at
                                     });
```

The html:

```
 <tr v-for="result in results">
    <td>
       <form class="form-inline" @submit.prevent='addToCart(result.id, $index)'>
          <input v-model="shoppingCart[$index].quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity" type="text">
          <select v-model="shoppingCart[$index].productTimeType" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="" selected="selected">All types</option><option value="1">Whole day</option><option value="2">Half day</option><option value="3">Per hour</option></select>
          <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="add to cart">
       </form>
```

When I debug this, and console.log the values it's doing it perfectly. Then it seems like there's some sort of refresh happening, and all the fields are reset on the page to what they were before, and no values are updated.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of your input to button instead of submit

```
<input class="btn btn-warning" type="button" value="add to cart">
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: did you use v-click and trigger from the button instead of submit?

Comment: @dannielum using the submit event is better because that is triggered using `enter` in the form

Comment: @dannielum - yes I did exactly that

Answer (score 0):

Ok,in my case the issue was with the fact that I was outputting the select box with Laravel using [Laravel Collective's package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html), and each time it did so, it generated the markup with a certain option selected. This was resetting the dropdown.

It would seem that there are better ways to work with VueJs and the backend like fetching the data or the html from the server and passing that to VueJs to generate the dropdown (if the dropdown is dynamic). I will follow an approach [similar to this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-use-vuejs-with-select-tags?page=2).